# My Iwatch does not get data saved from ios App even though I used AppGroup

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I have read and followed several instructions and videos in attempt to get my iphone and iwatch app use the same Userdefaults storage.
I have created an appgroup and used the appgroup name like this

```
preferences = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxxx.appname")!
```

but it still does not work as expected

I have read through almost all(if not all) questions related to this on stackoverflow, but I am still not getting expected result.

The last post I read suggested using WCSession, so I followed this url
http://www.codingexplorer.com/watch-connectivity-swift-application-context/

After all these attempts, my Iwatch is still unable to use the preferences/data I am setting on my ios app.

Any response would be appreciated towards fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Groups are no longer an option when attempting to access data on both of the devices.

You now need to use the [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) Framework.

Here's an example on how to use this:

**IOS**

```
import WatchConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate{

   override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported(){
            WCSession.default.activate()
            WCSession.default.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

**watchOS**

```
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate{

    override viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported(){
            WCSession.default.activate()
            WCSession.default.delegate = self
            let data = ["data1": 1, "data2": 2]
            WCSession.default.sendMessage(data, replyHandler: {reply in 
                print("Got reply \(reply)")
            }, errorHandler: {error in 
                print("Got error \(error)")
            })  
        }
    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {    
        print("Received \(message)") // ["data1": 1, "data2": 2]
        replyHandler(["messagedReceived": true])
    }
}
```

The above code isn't tested, but should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly the second thing I have tried when I followed this tutorial http://www.codingexplorer.com/watch-connectivity-swift-application-context/ as I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: This isn't using Application Context. Application Context is delivered at the OS's discretion, `sendMessage` is a lot quicker

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use WCSession.default.sendMessage. However I had to do session.activate() inside **override func willActivate() ** rather than in **awake** method